# App crashes with out of memory when capturing a photo in Cordova 3.0 app

Tags: android, cordova, out-of-memory

I am running a **Phonegap (Cordova 3.0) app** on my Android 2.3.6 Nexus One smartphone. My problem is that when I launch the camera and capture the image, after capture the app crashes and forced to be closed.

I used logcat app to take a look at the logs and this is what I have:

```
02-15 13:07:04.515 E/dalvikvm-heap( 5678): 3840000-byte external allocation too large     for this process.
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/GraphicsJNI( 5678): VM won't let us allocate 3840000 bytes
02-15 13:07:04.555 D/dalvikvm( 5678): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 56% free 3528K/8007K, external 21308K/23356K, paused 29ms
02-15 13:07:04.555 D/AndroidRuntime( 5678): Shutting down VM
02-15 13:07:04.555 W/dalvikvm( 5678): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size   exceeds VM budget
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at   android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.getScaledBitmap(CameraLauncher.java:618)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.onActivityResult(CameraLauncher.java:346)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(CordovaActivity.java:915)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-15 13:07:04.555 E/AndroidRuntime( 5678):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 13:07:04.565 W/ActivityManager(  118):   Force finishing activity com.test.app/.TelerikCallbackActivity
```

From what I can understand from the log files is that there is not enough memory to profess the captures image.

I am using `navigator.camera.getPicture` with `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` to capture the photo and process it. I tried lowering the image quality to 20 from 50 and it didn't solve the problem.

From the logs I can understand that the captured image from my Nexus One is around 3.7MB, although the JPEG captures is much smaller.

The app didn't crash on other devices that I've tried it on, only on my Nexus One, but my Nexus one has the lowest specs compared to the other phones.

I don't know how to solve this problem and need your help. Thanks.

**Update**: I lowered the resolution from 1600 pixels to 600 pixels (max for either width or height) and the camera captured the image successfully. However, I want to be able to capture a higher resolution on my Nexus One phone, at least 1600 pixels if it's possible in any way.

Comment: check this link http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/07/change-to-camera-code-in-phonegap-190.html

Comment: Helps thanks, but I still trying to figure out how to use the Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()  in order to solve my issue.